# FileNotFoundException on Named Pipe

Tags: c#, named-pipes

I have a named pipe client/server setup. The server runs inside a Windows hosted service. when i run my code on my localhost and dev integration environment, it runs fine; I am able to connect to the server through my named pipe client.
My client and server implementations are as follows:

As mentioned earlier, this works fine on my machine and the dev environment.
I have deployed this to the test server, however, each time my client connects to the server, it will throw FileNotFoundException. I have put try catch blocks at important places in the server code, but none of my server side code is able to handle this exception and my service fails with the exception.

Any insights as to why this could happen would be great.

**Edit**

I updated my code to use this:

```
private static PipeSecurity PipeSecurity
    {
        get
        {
            var security = new PipeSecurity();
            security.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Users", PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
            security.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("SYSTEM", PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            security.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow));
            security.AddAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AuthenticatedUserSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, AccessControlType.Allow));
            return security;
        }
    }


            var pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, MaxThreads, PipeTransmissionMode.Message, PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 1024, 1024, PipeSecurity);
            _logger.InfoFormat("CreatedServerInstance: {0}, Waiting for Connection.", _clientCount+1);
            pipeStream.WaitForConnection();
```

The exception seems to happen at the line pipeStream.WaitForConnection() as soon as the client connects. it is weird that it does not catch the exception and it fails the service right away. My service is running under Local System. 
Please note that i am not using those rules all at the same time, i just pasted it so that you know how that i have tried them all individually. I dug through the [source code explorer too](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/security/accesscontrol/nativeobjectsecurity.cs,2fcb990daf5d9db0)l that microsft have published to trace the source of FileNotFoundException. It seems to be coming from **system\security\accesscontrol\nativeobjectsecurity.cs**. This class is what the PipeSecurity class inherits from to call the base methods for SetAccessRule and AddAccessRule.

Answer (score 1):

When you work with named pipes you have to consider a few things:

**Naming**

Regarding the naming of the pipe, take a look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365783(v=vs.85).aspx. It explains that when you create the pipe, on the server, you must you the `\\.\pipe\PipeName` notation to identify the local machine (this is taken care of for you by the .NET wrappers). But when you connect to the pipe you must make sure you are connecting to the right server, by including the server name in the pipe URL. `\\ServerName\pipe\PipeName`

**Security**

The other aspect you have to consider is access control. You must make sure that the pipe is created with appropriate permissions to allow remote clients to connect to it. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365600(v=vs.85).aspx. Make sure that the ACL for the pipe is correctly set.

---

Based on your description of the issue it sounds like your issues are probably related to naming.

**UPDATE**

Here is some sample code from a server I wrote a while back:

```
private void SpawnServer()
{ 
    PipeSecurity pipeSa = new PipeSecurity();
    // let everyone read from the pipe but not write to it
    // this was my use case - others may be different
    pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule("Everyone", PipeAccessRights.Read, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
    pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinUsersSid, null), PipeAccessRights.Read, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
    pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.BuiltinAdministratorsSid, null), PipeAccessRights.ReadWrite, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));            
    pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.ServiceSid, null), PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
    pipeSa.SetAccessRule(new PipeAccessRule(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Owner, PipeAccessRights.FullControl, System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));            

    var pipeInstance = new NamedPipeServerStream(_pipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, 128, PipeTransmissionMode.Byte, PipeOptions.Asynchronous | PipeOptions.WriteThrough, 128, 128, pipeSa);
    PipeClient pipeClient = new PipeClient(pipeInstance, Interlocked.Increment(ref _totalclients));
    pipeInstance.BeginWaitForConnection(HandlePipeConnection, Tuple.Create(pipeInstance, pipeClient));
}

// this method asynchronously handles a new pipe connection and starts
// another server to handle other incoming connections
private void HandlePipeConnection(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var pipeServer = (ar.AsyncState as Tuple<NamedPipeServerStream, PipeClient>).Item1;
    var pipeClient = (ar.AsyncState as Tuple<NamedPipeServerStream, PipeClient>).Item2;
    try
    {
        pipeServer.EndWaitForConnection(ar);

        // not shown here, I had the server
        //   send the new client a message upon connect    
        // if (!pipeClient.SendMessage(announceMessage))
        //      throw new Exception("Send message failed for new pipe client connection!");

        pipeClient.Error += PipeClient_Error;
        pipeClient.Disposed += PipeClient_Disposed;
        pipeClient.MessagesReceived += PipeClient_MessagesReceived;

        pipeClient.Read();
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {                   
        // Log Exception
        pipeClient.Dispose();
    }

    try
    {
        SpawnServer();
    }
    catch (IOException)
    {
       // if an IO error occurs, most likely it's because max pipe clients reached..
       // in my case I was raising an event here
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
       // otherwise handle the error here (raise another event - not shown..)
    }
}
```

The code above uses a class called `PipeClient` which is a class I wrote that wraps a `NamedPipeClientStream` to expose it in a way that makes it easy to interface with clients. The class contains helper methods for reading and writing to a pipe client stream as well as some events which are raised when data is received (read) and when errors happen. I'm not going to paste the full class implementation since it's not directly relevant to the question but I will paste below the constructor

```
public class PipeClient
    : IDisposable
{    
    private PipeStream _pipeInstance = null;
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private int _clientId = 0;

    public PipeClient(PipeStream pipeInstance, int clientid)
    {
        _pipeInstance = pipeInstance;
        // this class can be used both by clients and by the server to
        //   represent connected clients 
        // on the server, the clients are already connected; for clients code they are not and the stream will be of a different kind
        if (!_pipeInstance.IsConnected && _pipeInstance is NamedPipeClientStream)
            ((NamedPipeClientStream)_pipeInstance).Connect(100);

        _clientId = clientid;

        // more internals being set up here (not shown) 
        //   such as buffers for reads, queue for messages to send out etc.
    }

    // convenience constructor to create a pipe client from a pipe name 
    public PipeClient(string pipeName, bool readOnly)
        : this(new NamedPipeClientStream(".", pipeName, readOnly ? PipeDirection.In : PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.Asynchronous), 0)
    {
    }

    // rest of the class not shown..
}
```

Comment: it was easy for me to change the name format on the client when it is trying to connect. however, still throws the same error. Regarding the security, my cleint is always going to run from the same server. I also verified that the particular named pipe is available to connect to when the windows service is started. it is only when the client connects that the service throws the error and stops. surprising thing is that it says that the exception is unhandled, which it is not since i have included try catches in all methods on the server.

Comment: @vaibinewbee even if you run your client on the same server - if the named pipe is created by a service it is highly likely that the service runs in a different process that may run with elevated privileges. You will have to make sure the client is allows to connect!

Comment: Ok. I will play around with the security stuff. Thanks for your guidelines.

Comment: As far as naming goes, I don't think I have to worry much about it. since as you mentioned, .net is wrapping it up for me, even when calling from the client. I can pass the server and named pipe name and it is normalized by the NamePipeClientStream object before calling the connect. Would it be possible for you to help me out personally (screen share, etc)? I am not sure if i am allowed to make such requests.. ;)

Comment: you're certainly allowed to make such requests :)  unfortunately I'm not sure when I would have the ability to help you out one-on-one since I don't have a lot of availability to do it; i will try to dig up some code I have written for this stuff and paste here in hopes it might get you unblocked

Comment: that sounds great.. I have also updated my question to reflect additional efforts to find what could be causing this issue.but i am not sure how to fix it. any help there would be great.

Comment: @vaibinewbee I've added some sample code the I've used; I hope it helps you more than it is confusing. I wrote my server (and clients) to be asynchronous - meaning that calls such as WaitForConnection wouldn't block